# Apply responsive layout for columns of specific class rather than every column class in the Page

Tags: html, css

I am using Media Query to make the columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other in case of the screen width is lesser than 960px.

```
@media screen and (max-width:960px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

But this applies this responsive feature to all column classes used. But I want this to be applied only to the main columns of my page rather than every column classes used in the page.

Any suggestions for this ?

Comment: It will be hard to tell without seeing your code ,But still i'd recommend you adding another class inside the div which you want to make it responsive and call that class

Comment: <div class="columns">
  <div class="column col-lg-4"></div>
  <div class="column col-lg-4"></div>
  <div class="column col-lg-4"></div>
</div>

Comment: Not like that, Give it like this <div class="columns column col-lg-4">

Comment: Sorry before I complete i pressed enter and it posted as comment, yes I do use like that

Comment: This is not the right way, Can you post the entire HTML ? Cuz its pretty hard to help you without seeing the whole code

Comment: @ThanveerShah i tested by adding another class and defining that in styles. and it worked, Thank you

Comment: Yup, That's exactly what I was telling you to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you'll have .main class added to your main columns

```
@media screen and (max-width:960px) {
  .main.column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```